# Read Word DOC stored as BLOB in MySQL database

Tags: mysql, coldfusion, blob, coldfusion-9

The MySQL database I'm working with stores Microsoft Word documents in a BLOB column.  However, I'm unable to grab the text content in the word document.  Any ideas?  I'm using ColdFusion 9.  I tried something like:

```
<cfset myText = toString(toBinary(BLOBText))>
```

but just got a bunch of jibberish.  Any help is appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: http://www.raymondcamden.com/index.cfm/2009/2/4/Reading-Office-documents-with-ColdFusion

Comment: Thank you. POI works great and I'm able to read simple Word documents that I create manually. My problem now is I'm trying to read a Word document stored as a LONGBLOB in MySQL, save it, and open it. The following error is received: "Object instantiation exception. An exception occurred while instantiating a Java object. The class must not be an interface or an abstract class. Error: ''."

Comment: Can you save the LONGBLOB as a .doc file, and open it with Word to see if it works?

Comment: Yes:

    <!--- get part text and save to DOC file --->
    <cfquery name="test" datasource="SentryEquip_MySQL">
 SELECT PartText
   FROM tblProductCatalog
   WHERE PartText IS NOT NULL
   LIMIT 1;
    </cfquery>

    <cfset myPartText = test.PartText>

    <cffile action="write" file="#application.AbsPath#\testdocs\test.doc" output="#myPartText#" />

Just displays a bunch of jibberish when I open in Word.  I also tried other variations before saving the file, such as:

    <cfset myPartText = toString(test.PartText)>

and

    <cfset myPartText = toString(toBinary(test.PartText))>

Comment: If this helps, I'm using POI 3.7 and, when opening the Word document, it says Word.Document.8 near the top.

Answer (score 5):

The word document isn't just plain text, it has lots of other information embedded in it as well. If you want to be able to parse the text, you'll need to either store the text itself before hand or load the full word document using some library in your code and read it out from there.

Comment: @JoshuaRowe, If you want to actually parse the text, then you'll need to (a) install OpenOffice on your CF server, (b) use the CFDOCUMENT tag to turn the Word doc into a PDF, and (c) use the CFPDF tag with action="extracttext". Hope this helps.

Comment: @DavidFaber - Actually you do not need to convert to pdf to extract the plain text. It can be done with POI. See Henry's link above.

Comment: @Leigh, that is true, I had forgotten about that as I was never able to get POI working correctly. :-)

Comment: @David - Yeah, it has its moments .. ;) but the text extraction is usually pretty good.

Comment: I had problems with the CFDOCUMENT/extracttext method, however, POI seemed to work okay, but only for files that I actually create myself in Microsoft Word.  It doesn't work with Word files saved as a LONGBLOB using MySQL.  Details on the error in my comment back to Henry above.